# WooCommerce REST API Error: #38761 is an invalid image ID. [woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id]

Tags: laravel, rest, woocommerce

I have an intermittent issue. Sometimes the product creates okay with the image.

Note that all images tested do have file extensions and are external links that have valid paths with an image.

Sometimes the REST API (codexshaper/laravel-woocommerce package) throws this error:

> "Error: #38761 is an invalid image ID. [woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id]"

It however still creates the product and image, but they're not linked.
Can't figure out why...

I even tried creating the product first then doing an update afterwards with the image, but it still only works sometimes.

```json
{
   "sku":"889698487405",
   "name":"Star Wars: the Mandalorian Child Funko Pop! Vinyl Figure 368",
   "type":"simple",
   "regular_price":"299.00",
   "description":"Star Wars: The Mandalorian Child Funko Pop! Vinyl Figure 368: The Force is strong with this youngling. Adorable 3 3/4-inch tall Pop! Vinyl figure brings you The Child! Inspired by the Disney+ Star Wars: The Mandalorian TV series. Get the 10-Inch 'Super Size' Child Pop! too! Sold separately.",
   "short_description":"Star Wars: The Mandalorian Child Funko Pop! Vinyl Figure 368: The Force is strong with this youngling. Adorable 3 3/4-inch tall Pop! Vinyl figure brings you The Child! Inspired by the Disney+ Star Wars: The Mandalorian TV series. Get the 10-Inch 'Super Size' Child Pop! too! Sold separately.",
   "categories":[
      
   ],
   "images":[
      {
         "src":"https://images.barcodelookup.com/16285/162854082-1.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "status":"draft",
   "manage_stock":true,
   "stock_quantity":1,
   "stock_status":"instock"
}
```

Comment: no `categories`?

Comment: I do send categories, the example just omits it

Comment: don't expect to debug code with code being omited

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case that the image you are using is `PNG` image not a `JPG` but the extension is `.jpg` this will cause this problem.

The extension is not correct. you should retain the correct image extension or convert it to the wanted format.

[image]

Comment: this doesn't seem to be the issue, as this image didn't upload at all and it seems fine: https://images.barcodelookup.com/59314/593143566-1.jpg

Comment: What are you using to create/save these photos? what software?
Check out this, does it work? https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZRG0.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Your image is PNG but url describes it as JPG.

Error comes from WP Validation logic, because wordpress is parsing extension from url.

If you would leave it without extension (for example https://via.placeholder.com/350x150) it would probably throw an error,  you can work around this with:

```php
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

placed in wp-config.php of your wordpress app.